# Calculate the value of the integral of a series

Tags: integration, power-series, laurent-series

> let $$P(r,\varphi):= \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} r^{|n|}e^{in\varphi} $$
>   with $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ 0< r <1$. Prove that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}P(r,\varphi)d\varphi =1$$

**My attempt:**

The infinite sum above it's a Laurent series, and it converges to $\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \dfrac{1-r^2}{1-2r \cos(\varphi) + r^2 } $ (the sum of the geometric series for positive and negative $n$). Since the series converge uniformly (by comparison with the geometric series $\sum_n r^n$), I have two ways of calculating this integral. First, $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \dfrac{1-r^2}{1-2r \cos(\varphi) + r^2 } d\varphi$$ and second $$ \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}  r^{|n|} \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{in\varphi} d\varphi$$.

**But** using the usual substitution $u = \tan \left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)$, and splitting the first integral (I have a problem in $\varphi = \pi$ with the substitution), and doing the limits (checked with mathematica), I obtain $0$ (the two integral are the same quantity but with different sign).

If I calculate the integral in the second, I obtain a sum of zeros, in fact, according to my calculations $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{in\varphi} d\varphi =0$.  But Mathematica evaluate correctly the integral, so I must be wrong somewhere.

Can someone help me figure out the problem? Or the reasoning is correct and I need to triple-check the calculations?

**Edit** Thanks to Daniel Fischer for pointing out that the second method works (just evaluate for $n=0$), So, why the first doesn't work? just miscalculations?

Comment: For the second way, don't forget $0\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer argh. Yeah, all zero but 1… ok, so the second way works, but why the first not? (I'll edit the question with proper credits to you, thanks)

Comment: I guess for the first way, at some point somebody thought $r > 1$. If you let $r\to 0$ in that integral, it's clear that the limit is $1$. Now you only need to see that it is independent of $r$ as long as $0 < r < 1$.

Comment: Or, maybe your difficulty at $\pi$ is the clue. Use the symmetry/periodicity to reduce the first integral to $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\varphi+r^2}\,d\varphi.$$

Comment: Also note that the integrand of the first integral is always positive, so the integral can not be zero. Probably you were already near the result but did some sign error.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the hints, I have some problem proving the periodicity/simmetry you mention. To be more precise, the function is even, and with period 2pi, how can I reduce it to your integral?

Comment: nevermind, I substituted $\varphi$ with $-\tilde{\varphi}$ and used the periodicity, and it works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative computation to the ones you tried above, relying on complex analysis.

For $n\ge0$, let $z=re^{i\varphi}$, so that we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{in\varphi}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{1-z}=f(z)$$
which is holomorphic in the open unit ball in $\mathbb{C}$. For $n<0$ let instead $w=re^{-i\varphi}$, so that:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}r^{|n|}e^{in\varphi}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty w^n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{w}{1-w}=g(w)$$
which again si a holomorphic function in the unit ball. Now notice that your integral splits into the integral of $f(z)$ over the circle with radius $r$ in the anticlockwise direction plus the integral of $g(w)$ over the circle with radius $r$ in the clockwise direction, and those can be easily computed using the residue theorem.

Namely we have:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{in\varphi}d\varphi=\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{1}{2i\pi}\frac{1}{z(1-z)}dz=1$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} r^{|n|}e^{in\varphi}d\varphi=\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{1}{-2i\pi}\frac{1}{1-w}dw=0$$